# APP-ID (application ID) who have to get it?

Tags: paypal

The question is that I use sandbox test app id. I'am developing a multivendor shopping cart with PayPal adaptive payments. I vill not use this cart. I sell it. And other users use it.

I make API User Id, API password and API signature parameters inside the shopping card to enable adaptive payments.

The question is, should my every client to request application ID when they setup their site or I have to acquire single global APP ID with will be used on all sites by all clients?

Comment: Do you mean "shopping cart"?

Comment: Thank you for at least spelling correction.

Comment: I hope this helps: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/lifecycle/goingLive/